# Using a crossfilter group with rickshaw

Tags: javascript, crossfilter, rickshaw

I'm experimenting with using crossfilter with rickshaw but I'm running into this problem:

Rickshaw expects its series data array to be composed of objects with x and y properties, where crossfilter outputs using the key and value properties.

So crossfilter outputs something like:

```
console.log(usersByProduct.all()[0]) // => Object {key: 1390291200, value: 249}
```

Which obviously is rejected by rickshaw with an error like this:

```
Uncaught x and y properties of points should be numbers instead of undefined and undefined
```

The only way I can think of getting it to work is: on any change to the underlying crossfilter, copy the crossfilter results to a new array and reset rickshaw with the new data, which seems really ugly and an unnecessary copy.

Does anybody have a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Rickshaw lets you set accessors on the graph like dc.js does, so you must give it the data in the format it expects. I think you'll have to explicitly set the updated data on the Rickshaw graph as you describe. You will have to call the render() method on your Rickshaw graph on any change to the Crossfilter in any case, won't you? So you can probably encapsulate resetting the data and calling .render() into a single function and just call that whenever your adjust your Crossfilter. But hopefully someone else will have a better idea.